# How to show content from footer in header using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show content which is in footer now. But I want to show it in header. Is it possible to show in header using `jquery` or `javascript`?

Comment: Maybe provide us with some code?

Comment: can share screen shot?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vinayakmali123/dLykpjxr/           Please check above example I want to show content which is at bottom actully I want show that content in Header using jquery

Comment: @vinayakmali post your code. This will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to achieve with that, maybe a few more information would be useful. But you can do what you describe with following code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function changeHeader()
  {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="changeHeader()">
  <div id="header" onclick="test()"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>test1</p>
    <p>test2</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you dont want to show the data in footer anymore, you can add following line:

```
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show content of footer in header, then in javascript you can write -

HTML -

```
<html>
<body>
<header id="header"></header>

<footer id="footer">Footer Content</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Script -

```
document.getElementById('header').innerHTML= document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML
```

And to make footer fill with some other content -

```
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = 'Some other Content'
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#header').html($('#footer').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Header:</h3>
<div id="header">
</div>
<h3>Footer:</h3>
<div id="footer">
Some <i>HTML</i>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Here’s JS that does exactly what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('header').html($('footer').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/dLykpjxr/4/) it is what you are looking for, hope it works for you.

`footer = $('#move_to_Header').html();
header = $('#thisisheader').html();
$('#thisisheader').html(footer);
$('#move_to_Header').html(header);`